# How to properly specify a complex type in the proxy class?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a **ServiceContract** on the server like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICheckService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Message> CheckInbox(string user);
}
```

I copied above definition into the **proxy class** on the client:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICheckService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Message> CheckInbox(string user);
}
```

When I am compiling the client, I get the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Message' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
```

Message.cs

```
public class Message
{
    public int message_id;
    public string message_from;
    public string message_to;
    public string message_text;
    public DateTime message_time;
}
```

Is this where `DataContracts` come into play? If so, What should I modify in the ServiceContract definition?

Note: The ServiceContract has other OperationContracts which return simple data types and are working.

Comment: Is the Message class the built in Message class or is it a custom class?

Comment: @SCB: It is a custom class. I included its definition now.

Comment: Ok, check @chris answer below. This should be what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[DataContract]
public class Message{
[DataMember]
public String Sender{get;set;}
//etc - not sure what your message class contains
}
```

Something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `WCF` is a message communication framework, These messages are `DataContracts` , in other words they are classes decorated by `DataContract` attribute, in order  to inform  `WCF` that this objects from this class will communicate or travel through the service. In your example you are sending a set of objects to your client ,then this `class` should be a `DataContract` and properties which are supposed to be visible for the client should be decorated with `DataMember` attribute.

```
 [DataContract]
 public class Message
 {
   [DataMember]
   public string Name{get;set;}
 }
```

Therefore, you should modify your contract `Message` and not the Service Contract